# autocomplete with category in php mysql is not working

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What I want to do is have categorised results using autocomplete through jQueryUI's function. After some googling etc I found that it has an inbuilt function (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories) but the example is only for a local data source (an array in javascript). I am dealing with a remote data source. 
 MY code is

```
<script>
$( function() {
 $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
    var self = this,
        currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        self._renderItem(ul, item);
    });
}
});
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay:0,
    source: "search.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
    alert(ui.item.label);
}
});
} );
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
</body>
```

here is **search.php**

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die(mysqli_error());
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
 $sql = "select * from country_ref_table where country_code LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY country_code ASC";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $data = [];
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $data[] = $row['country_code'];
   $data[] = $row['country'];
  }
 echo json_encode($data);
  ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you forgot to add $searchTerm  in query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
 $sql = "select * from country_ref_table";
```

add it in $sql

```
 $sql = "select * from country_ref_table where `term` LIKE '%".$searchTerm ."%'";
```

then use data like this :

```
$data=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $data[]['id'] = $row['country_code'];
   $data[]['category'] = $row['country'];
  }
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: what is your category column name in DB, replace it in where condition

Comment: catagory column name is `country`

Comment: then use this:

 $sql = "select * from country_ref_table where `country` LIKE '%".$searchTerm ."%'";

Comment: $data=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $data[]['id'] = $row['country_code'];
   $data[]['category'] = $row['country'];
  }
 echo json_encode($data);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
 $sql = "select * from country_ref_table";
```

You need to include the `$searchTerm` in your query, somewhat like:

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "select * from country_ref_table WHERE `columnTerm` LIKE '%".$searchTerm ."%' ";
```

OR

```
$sql = "select * from country_ref_table WHERE `columnTerm` = '$searchTerm' ";
```